# TRAC: how to add a component/milestone to a wiki page?

Tags: plugins, trac

TRAC tends to separate wiki pages and tickets quite a lot, but there is definitely an argument for cross-reference.

I know that the [TagsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TagsPlugin) unifies both ticket "Keywords" and a new "Tag" list for wiki pages. I'm looking for a similar functionality for `component`s and `milestone`s. Is it possible with TRAC 0.11? If not, what about more recent versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do I understand correctly, that you request/vote for tagging Trac resources `milestone` and `component`? This is reasonable, and could be done, because [TagsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TagsPlugin) is ready for tagging arbitrary Trac realms just by implementing the `ITagProvider` interface, i.e. by subclassing `DefaultTagProvider`, and you're up and running with the generic tag store in Trac db table `tags` as tag store.

Or is your request more about functionality like that provided by

- [ComponentsProcessorMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ComponentsProcessorMacro) - listing project components with descriptions
- [ListMilestonesMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ListMilestonesMacro) - shows a list of chosen Milestones
- [MilestoneCompactMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MilestoneCompactMacro) - milestones displayed in compact table or list
- [MilestoneQueryMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MilestoneQueryMacro) - displays a list of matching milestones
- [PlannedMilestonesMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/PlannedMilestonesMacro) - lists milestones ordered by their due dates

Comment: I basically want to be able to tag a page against a `component` or `milestone` (maybe multiple) and then see the wiki pages associated to a `milestone` in its `/milestone/MyMilestone` page and also in the `component`'s page (if there is one?). Thanks for the list of plugins, they are useful in their own right! (especially the first two)

Comment: if [`TagsPlugin`'s `ListTagged`](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TagsPlugin#ListTaggedmacro) could show pages/issues with certain tags but also restricted by milestone/components, that would be great. e.g. if I have a tag called "idea", I'd want to see all the idea pages listed under a given milestone/component.

Comment: Currently there's no connection between wiki pages and components/milestones similar to the fields in tickets. TagsPlugin could really help in that respect, i.e. by using component and/or milestone names for tagging wiki pages. If this is, what you want, I'd appreciate an enhancement request for that plugin, that makes this and foreseen use cases as clear as possible.